# Prove that if $f$ is an integrable function such that $\int_Ef\geq0$ for every measurable set $E$ then $f\geq0$ a.e..

Tags: measure-theory

Suppose $f$ is an integrable function such that $\int_Ef\geq0$ for every measurable set $E$. Then it is needed to prove that $f\geq0$ a.e.

We need to prove that $m(H)=0$, where $H=\{x\in\mathbb{R}:f(x)<0\}=m(\{x\in\mathbb{R}:f^+(x)<f^-(x)\})$.

Here $f^+(x)=\max\{f(x),0\}$ and $f^-(x)=\max\{-f(x),0\}$.

Then I thought of doing something like the following.

Assume $m(H)>0$. But $H=\bigcup_{q\in\mathbb{ Q}}\{x\in\mathbb{R}:f^+(x)<q\}\cap\{x\in\mathbb{R}:f^-(x)>q\}$. So there exists $q\in\mathbb{Q}$ such that $m(G)>0$ where $G=\{x\in\mathbb{R}:f^+(x)<q\}\cap\{x\in\mathbb{R}:f^-(x)>q\}$.

Now I seem to be going nowhere. Could some one please show me the directions to this proof? Thank you

**Added Later:** $H$ is a measurable set. Suppose $m(H)>0$. On $H$ we have $f^+\equiv 0$ and $f^-\equiv -f$. Now $0\leq\int_H f=\int_H-f^-=-\int_Hf^-<0$ because $\int_Hf^-\geq0$ and $\int_Hf^-=0$ iff $f^-\equiv0$ a.e. on $H$. Thus we have a contradiction. Hence $m(H)=0$.

Comment: Why don't you start taking $E=H$?

Comment: The problem is that $H$ is not necessarily a measurable set. How do you suggest using $H$ though?

Comment: Oh really? I am a bit surprised, as $f$ should be a measurable function and so $H$ a measurable set. But maybe your definitions are different than the ones I refer to. At any rate, if $H$ is measurable then integrating $f$ on it you should discover that $\int f^- =0$. This looks like a progress, since what we are trying to show is that $f^-$ vanishes (almost everywhere).

Comment: You are right. $H$ is measurable. I thought that a function need not be measurable in order for it to be integrable. But after your comment I checked my notes!

Comment: Could you please check the "added later" part?

Comment: The "added later" part looks perfect.